# Webkit scrollbar bug on mousedown

Tags: css, dom, webkit, scroll

I experience strange behaviour with vertical scrollbars in webkit based browsers (Chrome and Safari). The vertical scrollbar in my example is visible as desired and works when scrolling with the mouse-wheel.

The strange thing is that it's impossible to scroll by clicking the scrollbar.

I managed to isolate the error to a simple jQueryUI example.

```
$(function() {
  var $el = $('<div><div class="huge" style="height:2000px">Webkit can\'t scroll.</div></div>');
  $el.dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Webkit Scrollbar',
    width: 500
  });
});
```

A running demo with the necessary html is available here http://jsbin.com/uculem/8. Try scrolling by clicking the scrollbar and moving the bar around.

When taking the complete DOM produced by jQueryUI from the chrome debugger and pasting it to a new html file everything works again. See here: http://jsbin.com/ahitev/2

I'm grateful for any hint what could cause this. Every workaround is appreciated.

Thanks,

Florian

**Edit**

As tw16 pointed out this occurs in webkit browsers when the mousedown event is captured by javascript code. This seems to be a bug in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19033

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. As you can see here: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4671

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari), the code below was suggested as an answer.

```
$el.dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay')
                            .unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay');
        }, 100);
    },
    modal: true,
    title: 'Webkit Scrollbar',
    width: 500
});
```

Apparently jQueryUI prevents scrolling by capturing the mouseup / mousedown events.