# jQuery UI dialog blocking window scroll bar in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am facing a problem when using jQuery UI dialog box. When I open a photo in jQuery dialog box, it freezes the window scroll bar. I am not able to move up or down the page using the mouse pointer. This problem exists only in Google Chrome. Its working fine in Mozilla and Internet Explorer.
Does any one have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Scrollbar problem with jQuery UI dialog in Chrome and Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: Please, show the code you are using.

Comment: In the duplicate link above, search the answer with a link to a patch. It is a 1 line patch and works perfectly.

Comment: Please see answer from this forum: [Scrollbar problem with jQuery UI dialog in Chrome and Safari][1].

Hope this help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed a similar glitch in the past by doing the following right before initializing the dialog:

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function () {
    this.uiDialog.draggable({
        containment: false,
        handle: "div.ui-widget-header",
        cancel: "#dialogId"
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue when I open a jQueryUI dialog that has a TimyMCE editor in it. The scrollbars in the dialog were freezing.

The weird reason for it a URL HASH '#' in the end of the url. The URL HASH was added to the url because I forgot to 'return false;' in the click() event of the link that opened the dialog. Once I added the 'return false;' the event was not natively handled by the browser, no URL HASH was added and the scrollbars of the dialog worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occur when I was using jquery UI dialog box in chrome, try to give some fix height to box this will not freeze