# Jquery modal dialogs DISABLE the scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog, scrollbar

As you can see on this link, 
http://jsbin.com/ozapol/9 ,

Jquery disables the scrollbars on some versions of IE and the latest version of chrome.
(I didnt try any other yet...)

Is there a way to keep scrollbars enabled to be able to scroll through a long long dialog ?

Thank you !
Bye

**Nice solution for Internet Explorer** (Thanks to jk.)

```
html {overflow-y : scroll}
```

**Brutal workaround for Chrome** (Thanks to jk.)

On Chrome, JqueryUI Hijacks mouse events on the scrollbars.
This looks like a bug that is referred in the links above.
In order to remove those bindings, you have to unbind events
each time you create a modal dialog :

```
$("#longdialog").dialog({
     open: function(event, ui) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay')
                            .unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay');
        }, 100);
    },
   modal:true
});
```

There is the final example : http://jsbin.com/ujagov/2

**Links to bug reports :**

1. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4671
2. http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34725121/Visual-Test-Page-Cleanup

Comment: Why don't you try adding a scrollbar inside the dialog?

Comment: Because this doesn't make sens in my application ... Sorry

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollbar problem with jQuery UI dialog in Chrome and Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep scrollbars enabled with:

```
html {overflow-y: scroll;}
```

You could add that CSS programmatically so it doesn't affect every page of the site and possibly the design.

And, you may have to unbind the mouse events that the modal dialog hijacks:

```
$("#longdialog").dialog({
     open: function(event, ui) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(document).unbind('mousedown.dialog-overlay')
                            .unbind('mouseup.dialog-overlay');
        }, 100);
    },
   modal:true
});
```

See [Scrollbar problem with jQuery UI dialog in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617638/scrollbar-problem-with-jquery-ui-dialog-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for you answer but unfortunately this doesn't look to  work. I added this CSS part in my sample and it's still not working : http://jsbin.com/ozapol/5

Comment: Actually it does work on Internet explorer but it doesn't on Chrome... Any Idea ?

Comment: @NicolasThery Works for me in Chrome on the Mac and PC. Not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: It's not working either on version 16.0.912.75 for Windows nor the version 16.0.912.77 that I just installed.

Comment: @NicolasThery I have the same version of Chrome on my Windows PC. Is there something else in the styles that may be overriding the overflow-y setting?

Comment: Do you really get the scrollbars working on that piece of code ?! http://jsbin.com/ozapol/9

Comment: @NicolasThery Yes, but it only works with the scrollwheel. Try this: http://jsbin.com/ujagov/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Works with jQuery UI 1.8

Answer (score 2):

This bug fixed at jQueryUi-1.10.
Here is link with the issue http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4671.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your css-file:

```
 .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;

 }
 #longdialog{
    height: 450px;

 }
```

The overflow doesn't work because the height was set to auto, define a specific height to the container div

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont want the scroll bar inside the dialog but for the whole page. I dont want many scroll bars in my interface. I updated the example :http://jsbin.com/ozapol/9

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or can't upgrade to jQuery UI 1.10, this is the solution for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740756/354756